# opencv 3.1 cuda 7.5 building drops Error. LNK2019. Linker is okey in VS 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

It's not my first `openCV` build just to know :) Now, I made my own library with `cMake` with contribute `lib.-s` and `CUDA 7.5`. I build 64-bit and my compiler is `VS 12 2013 x64` (a read that u cannot use `CUDA lib.-s` if its not compiled 64-bit.).

Now I did as before, just like many tutorials and so ever, and I cannot build my `opencv_videoio300.dll`. I have the lib, but nothing else.

```
Error 97 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: long __cdecl videoInput::getDevice(struct IBaseFilter * *,int,wchar_t *,char *)" (?getDevice@videoInput@@AEAAJPEAPEAUIBaseFilter@@HPEA_WPEAD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual double __cdecl cv::VideoCapture_DShow::getProperty(int)const " (?getProperty@VideoCapture_DShow@cv@@UEBANH@Z) C:\opencv3\build\modules\videoio\cap_dshow.obj 1

Error 98 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\opencv3\build\bin\Release\opencv_videoio300.dll
```

This is the only error in the whole `INSTALL` build. Cannot figure out whats the problem. Any suggestion?

On 32-bit, everything is perfect with the `openCV` binaries and `lib.-s` but on 32-bit I cannot compile `opencv_cudaarithm300.dll`, c`opencv_cudawarping300.dll` and `opencv_cudalegacy300.dll`;

Now I'm in a situation, where I need to have a normal build with `OpenCV 3.1` and with `CUDA 7.5`, and I don't care its 32 or 64 bit". I'm desperate now

Comment: Are you building 3.0 or 3.1? Also, have you built a cuda sample to make sure your cuda is installed correctly? BTW, I didn't check `WITH_NVCUVID` in CMAKE when building opencv 3.0 on my PC, because NVENC SDK couldn't work with opencv back then. Not sure if nvcuvid works with 3.1 now, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I just solved the problem. Yes i said wrong, i used openCV 3.0. Now i use openCV 3.1 with CUDA 7.5 and everything is perfect now. I think the main issue was, that nVidia doesn't support 32bit CUDA, but openCV 3.0 doesn't compiled correctly on 64bit also.
Now openCV 3.1 is stable and compiled/built correctly on 64 bit.

So problem solved.